# C# UDP An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp

I am creating a server for a game that handles multiple clients over `UDP` using the asynchronous methods, and am specifically working on clean disconnect logic. When a client hard crashes (their program is closed without proper disconnect logic) the `readCallback` on the server throws the SocketException

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

which makes sense, however when the read is triggered the next time on the loop in `read` it crashes despite the exception being handled in the callback.

```
    private void connectedState()
    {
        while (connected)
        {
            //reset the trigger to non-signaled
            readDone.Reset();

            read(socket);

            //block on reading data
            readDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }


    private void read(Socket sock)
    {
        // Creates an IpEndPoint to capture the identity of the sending host.
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint senderRemote = sender;

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = sock;

        //crashes after an exception is caught within the callback
        sock.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.MESSAGE_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ref senderRemote, new AsyncCallback(readCallback), state);
    }


    private void readCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket sock = state.workSocket;

        EndPoint senderRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        try
        {
            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = sock.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref senderRemote);

            if (bytesRead <= 0)
            {
                //handle disconnect logic
            }
            else
            {
                //handle the message received
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.ToString());
        }

        // Signal the read thread to continue
        readDone.Set();
    }
```

Two exceptions are thrown, one of which I believe is being caught:

---

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult asyncResult, EndPoint& endPoint)
   at CardCatacombs.Utilities.Networking.UDPNetworkConnection.readCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\Users\kayas\Desktop\Practicum\Source\CardCatacombs\CardCatacombs\Utilities\Networking\UDPNetworkConnection.cs:line 424

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBeginReceiveFrom(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress, OverlappedAsyncResult asyncResult)

---

I would like to be able to cleanly handle a client crash and continue running since there are other clients connected to the server.

Comment: It's unclear where the code is crashing. Please clarify and post the exception. Socket IO does not have special exception rules. Exceptions always work the same way and will be caught.

Comment: Note, that your use of async IO makes no sense. Since you are blocking on events you get the worst of both worlds: Callbacks and limited scalability. Use sync IO and do not blindly copy bad sample code.

Comment: Seeing your edit: You still need to provide the exception which will clarify where exactly it occurs. Also, what do you mean by "crash"? I should have asked that right away.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the exceptions that are thrown, and clarified what I mean by crashing. Hopefully that helps, although the sample code obviously does not show the line numbers

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the APM pattern. Maybe you need to try-catch guard the Begin call as well. You correctly guarded the End call. Of course the "handle disconnect logic" logic must also appear in the catch. Hard to say whats going on without more complete code and without a better description of the symptoms. Does crash mean that the console app exits without warning?

Comment: When the exception is thrown on the server, the thread that all networked receive calls are performed on crashes. I was originally using the synchronous method for networking, but attempted to change it after running into an issue that others suggested was an inherent flaw of C#. It's possible that the better solution is to seek a workaround for the issue with the synchronous method.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did you use the socket's low-level IOControl ?

Answer (score 22):

From [this forum thread](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks.narkive.com/RlxW2V6m/udp-comms-and-connection-reset-problem), it seems that the UDP socket is also receiving ICMP messages and throwing exceptions when they are received. If the port is no longer listening (after the hard crash), the ICMP message causes the 'forcibly closed' exception.

If not wanted, this exception can be disabled using the following code when creating the UdpClient, explained in the above post:

```cs
public const int SIO_UDP_CONNRESET = -1744830452;
var client = new UdpClient(endpoint);
client.Client.IOControl(
    (IOControlCode)SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, 
    new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
    null
);
```

For dotnet core users, since this "Socket.IOControl" is a Windows-specific control code, other platforms are not supported, we will get the below exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Socket.IOControl handles Windows-specific control codes and is not supported on this platform.

For better compatibility, we should check the current platform:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InterosServices;

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, further more, for the dotnet core users, this "Socket.IOControl" is a Windows-specific control code, other platforms are not supported.

Comment: this saved me :) 

If you, like me, use a socket direcly, instead of a UdpClient, you can use

socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            const int SIO_UDP_CONNRESET = -1744830452;
            socket.IOControl((IOControlCode)SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, null);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
            IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30000);
            socket.Bind(server);